# Opening more than two tabs with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently using chrome(selenium) to automate something for me. For some reason I cannot get selenium to open up another webpage.

```
def gotoInventory():
   #WebDriverWait(driver,5)
   inventoryPS = driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
   inventoryPS

   openInventoryTab = driver.execute_script("window.open('https://sellercentral.amazon.com/inventoryplanning/dashboard','new window')")
   openInventoryTab

def loginProton():

    #Need to create a new tab to open proton mail  
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    #above code did not work

    #also tried browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

    openProtonTab = driver.execute_script("window.open('https://mail.protonmail.com/login','new window')")
    openProtonTab
```

For some reason selenium always opens the webpage on the inventory tab which is not what I want. protonMail has to be opened on its own tab and not on the inventory tab.

Any help would be greatly apperciated

Comment: You forgot to `driver.switch_to.window("tab name")`

Comment: But I need to open the third webpage first before I can switch. The problem selenium isn't opening a 3rd tab for me to switch to

Comment: The JavaScript code you're executing has the same window name in both cases which is: 'new window'. Try using different window names in inventory and proton cases. Also note, that window.open creates a browser window.

Comment: @Apostolos Emmanouilidis thanks man, this worked \

Comment: @Xavier-UrielEspinal you're welcome. i've added my comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens due to using the same window name in both cases which is 'new window'. You may try using different window names in inventory and proton cases. Also note that window.open creates a browser window.